# AuthorizeAttribute behavior in ASP.NET MVC when authentication mode is set to Windows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, authorization

I have a controller protected with `AuthorizeAttribute`. When the authorization fails i get just an empty page. If i override `OnAuthorization()` i can see that after calling `base.OnAuthorization()` `filterContext.Result` is null (why?). If i override `OnException()` and set a breakpoint it never hits. Can please someone explain how it's supposed to work? How can i make it redirect to specified page? Where can i inject into to log failed authorization attempts (better not to write custom filter)? I use MVC 3 RC1 if it's important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to override the AuthorizeAttribute.HandleUnauthorizedRequest method.  Here's the default implementation:

```
protected virtual void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
    // Returns HTTP 401 - see comment in HttpUnauthorizedResult.cs.
    filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}
```

You'll instead want to set the Result to be a RedirectResult (or some other result depending on your desired logic).  This would also be a good place for logging.